# Symfony2 routing behaves different in prod environment

Tags: symfony, routes, production-environment

I can't figure this one out.

At first let me say that my cache is cleared. I went so far as to delete the prod and dev directories in app/cache. So this is no issue of non updated prod routes.

Here is my router:debug output:

**Prod:** app/console router:debug --env=prod:

```
[router] Current routes
Name            Method Pattern
instrumentlabel ANY    /backend/instrumentlabel/{page}/{filter}
marketmapping   ANY    /backend/marketmapping/{page}/{filter}
```

**Dev:** app/console router:debug --env=dev

```
[router] Current routes
Name            Method Pattern
instrumentlabel ANY    /backend/instrumentlabel/{page}/{filter}
marketmapping   ANY    /backend/marketmapping/{page}/{filter}
```

Both are the same (there's no distinction in my configuration).

Acessing `/backend/instrumentlabel` works in both environments. But when I try to access `/backend/marketmapping` it only works in the dev environment.

In the prod environment I'm always redirected to `/backend/marketmapping/` (notice the leading slash) for no reason.

My `prod.log` simply states:

```
 request.ERROR: [...]: No route found for "GET /backend/marketmapping/"
```

Comment: Could you show the related routing.yml and maybe the routing_dev.yml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out **this was in fact a browser caching issue**.

I realized that FireFox stated that `/backend/marketmapping` moved permanently (HTTP 301) to `/backend/marketmapping/`.

A week ago I had to alter the routing. Before that Symfony2 must have been responding to a request to `/backend/marketmapping` with a 301 to `/backend/marketmapping/`. My FireFox cached that information (but only in the prod environment, in dev this was a 302 which must not be cached by the browser).

I realized this after I checked the routes in Opera where everything worked fine.

To whom it may concern:

To force FireFox to forget cache redirects you can follow these directions:

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=1995719

---

Its funny how most of your questions get answered by yourself right after you ask them.